# Weirdness reading Microsoft Excel .xlsx in Java. Parsing works fine on some machines and not others

Tags: java, excel, parsing, spreadsheet

(1) Java program reads MS excel .xlsx spreadsheet. Jar with Maven dependencies including Excel reader package.
(2) Download customer .xlsx file and program processes the spreadsheet fine when run in Mac terminal or Windows emulator. Same program runs fine for colleague in his laptop.
(3) customer IT guy downloads same file to his Windows Server. Same program does not process file properly.
(4)Send the file via email to IT guy,  the file that worked for me. Surprise! It works for him!

I am not modifying the spreadsheet in any way.

I can only reason since this Excel is generated by report writer there us something off? Or a server setting?

Comment: You don't give ask the details about network locations etc for downloads etc so just a guess: file is blocked when "downloaded from Internet" - check properties/ check file can be opened by something else like Excel.

Comment: Again a guess – there's no gui on the Windows server so it affects certain 'graphical' Java classes adversely. Maybe run with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` as a VM parameter if true

Comment: What exactly does "does not process file properly" mean?

Comment: The program when operating correctly (1) parses a header row that contains date values e.g. 1.21, 2.21.(2l Iterates through each row and finds a numeric value in first position that represents a project code. The program looks up the found project code in the spreadsheet with a target system and updates the value in a target row. Oddly, this happened before where  I see a non-sensical value like 4444 in the header row field but customer sees 1.21,  2.21 representing date and month.

Comment: Also their IT department downloads directly to the server file system. The excel file can be opened by the java program.